# rounding of "hotness" points is inconsistent

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-exchange, stack-exchange-button

On the Stack Exchange homepage, hotness points are rounded appropriately, but in the super multi collider whatsit thingy, they're always rounded down.

[image]

In that example, the question has 151.966 hotness points

Comment: couldn't this also be an issue of caching comparing the time both items were loaded? Maybe it was 151.45 at the time the top nav loaded?

Comment: @Jeff: Possibly, although I refreshed the page very quickly a few times as the hotness points were dropping, which is how I caught it at `151.966` for the main page.  I guess if the collider loads afterward via ajax then the difference could be due to the time it takes to load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are cached by completely different mechanisms, so there may be a slight discrepancy depending on when the caching occurs...we're okay with that.  If it's off by a wide margin we'd take another look, but it's unlikely to change given how they get and cache their data at the most basic level.

Comment: If you're ok with it Nick, then so am I ;-)